# Add text to web page from code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am generating some text in the code-behind of web page on button click event. Earlier, in one of my desktop application, I was doing something like this.

For e.g.:

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
      {
         Label txtLabel1 = new Label(Text=i.ToString(), Color=Blue}; //Generating a label
         StackPanel1.Children.Add(txtLabel1); //Adding a label to stack panel on the desktop app
      }
      for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
      {
         Label txtLabel2 = new Label(Text=j.ToString(), Color=Red}; //Generating a label
         StackPanel2.Children.Add(txtLabel1); //Adding a label to stack panel on the desktop app
      }
}
```

I do not have much experience with web development and so I am a little confused on how to do the similar thing in my ASP.NET website. In my .aspx.cs code, I can generate the strings but from the code-behind, how do I add them to the page along with their color properties as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a StackPanel, use a placeholder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="ph1" run="server" />
```

You can then use ph1.Controls.Add(...

Regards to styling the label, you can use label1.Style.Add("color", "red")

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            Label txtLabel1 = new Label(); //Generating a label
            txtLabel1.Text = i.ToString();
            txtLabel1.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
            ph1.Controls.Add(txtLabel1);
        }
```

Comment: The way I have already given a color property to the generated label, when I add this to PlaceHolder do I still need to use the styles here?

Comment: As this is a web app, you have to add a style to the label to change its colour. This is done either by adding a style like shown, or you could add a class to the label, and add a css class to the page that contains the style.